# Python script runs fine locally but get a JSONDecodeError when running in Github Actions

Tags: python, python-requests, github-actions

I have the following code:

```
import requests
import boto3
import os

# Fetch data from API
response = requests.get('https://api.example.com')
data = response.json()

# Upload data to S3 bucket
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'))

bucket_name = 'api-collector'
folder_name = 'collection'
object_name = 'test'

s3_client.put_object(Body=str(data), Bucket=bucket_name, Key='{}/{}'.format(folder_name, object_name))
```

The API request works fine on my local version however in Github Actions it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/api-collector/api-collector/folder/api.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = response.json()
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

this is what my .yaml file looks like:

```
name: api_to_s3

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  upload:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: api_to_s3
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      run: |
        python folder/api.py
```

Anything i am missing here? Thanks!

Comment: How are you replacing your env variables in your python code?

Comment: Can you print the response status code just before `response.json()`? or add a try/catch perhaps to make it easier to understand why the request is failing.

Comment: Sorry @Fcmam5 i have updated code (i was using old)

Comment: @Bunny howdo i print the response status code?

Comment: `Response status code: 200` @Bunny

Comment: Try to print the `response.content` in that case during the script execution on the Github Action workflow. To check the `response` structure (`print(response.content)`)

Comment: `is unavailable from your location</h1>             <p>It appears you are visiting our website from a country we are unable to give access to`

Comment: This may be the reason @GuiFalourd

Comment: You got it ! 

Comment: Looks like there is no way to change to an `Australia` server unless i make a custom runner? Maybe AwS CodePipeline might be better for me @GuiFalourd

Comment: @SOK: Or, you can use a proxy server to access it.